# XML delete tag based on the match

Tags: python-3.x

Need to delete the vrfName tag from the payload

```
<Test>
<Sub>
<vrfName>management</vrfName>
</Sub>
<sub1>
<vrfName>management</vrfName>
</sub1>
<host>
<vrfName>management</vrfName>
</host>
</Test>
```

import re
        from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

```
    root = ET.parse("test.xml").getroot()
    print(root)
    regex=r'<vrfName>\w+</vrfName>'
    sa=open('test.xml','r')
    x=sa.readlines()
    for i in x:`
            match=re.findall(regex,i)
            match=''.join(match)
            print(match)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What did you expect your code to do and what was the actual result?

Comment: Never "parse" XML with a regex. Get a real XML parser.